# Handle data between different fragments using ViewModel and update

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel

I'm trying to implement a datepicker fragment which then has to return the chosen date to the fragment (parent fragment) calling it. I've implemented an interface but it seems that the interface only gets called in the activity, not in the fragment (even if I explicitly call it). I checked this out with log files.

So then I proceeded to use ViewModel class to hold data. Now the problem is, I'm able to store the data in the ViewModel class but I don't know where to call the function of ViewModel in the parent fragment. Calling it on OnCreate/OnCreateView does not help since the fragment has already loaded. Calling it on OnResume/OnAttach crashes the app with null pointer reference.

```
public class ShareData extends ViewModel{

private int year, month, day;

private String date;

public void getDate(int y, int m, int d)
{
    Log.d("Viewmodel is", Integer.toString(year) + " " + Integer.toString(month) + " " + Integer.toString(day));
    year = y;
    month = m;
    day = d;
}

public String setDate()
{

    return (Integer.toString(year) + "-" + Integer.toString(month) + "-" + Integer.toString(day));
}
```

}

This is the code from the DatePicker dialogfragment:

```
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        viewModel.getDate(year,month+1,day);
        datePicked.onDatePicked(view, year, month+1, day);
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
```

And this is my parent fragment:

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.operations_static_new, container, false);
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.patient_name);
        id = view.findViewById(R.id.patient_id);
        date_textview = view.findViewById(R.id.date_static);

        date_textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                confirmDatePicker(); //this opens fragment to choose date
            }
        });
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ShareData.class);
     date_textview.setText(model.setDate());
}
```

Where do I call date_textview.setText so that the date gets shown on the textview of the date picker?

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to instantiate a ViewModel in `onActivityCreated`, try it.

Comment: Yeah I did that. But the textview.setText has to be called AFTER I have already entered date from the dailogfragment. For now, I've implemented it by calling .setText on buttonclick of another button. Its a bad solution but well.

Comment: I don't fully understand, you can declare the ViewModel as `private ViewModel model`, instantiate it in `onActivityCreated` and then `setText` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any LiveData inside your ViewModel, which tells me you are not using it correctly. What you should do is bind LiveData inside the ViewModel to the fragment you want updated. After that it is trivial to recieve notification of changes in any fragment that is observing the ViewModel.

So to start with your ViewModel should look something like this:

```
// This will now notify the fragment that is observing of any changes made
public class SharedData extends ViewModel {
    private int year, month, day;
    private MutableLiveData<String> date = new MutableLiveData<>();

    // This will notify observing fragments of changes
    public void setDate(int y, int m, int d) {
        year = y; month = m; day = d;
        date.setValue(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
    }

    // This is a factory method for getting the LiveData the fragment will bind to
    public LiveData<String> getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

Inside the fragment (parent) that updates on date change you do something like this to monitor getDate() from the example above. Which is what is needed for the update to happen after the child or anything else is done updating:

Replace

```
date_textview.setText(model.setDate());
```

with

```
viewModel.getDate().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String newDate) {
                // Update your view with the new data
                dateTextView.setText(newDate);
            }
        });
```

After the setup is done, you can call setDate(y,m,d) from wherever you want, and it will always update the fragments that are observing it.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodelhttps://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel